# DataGridView not resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I have a WinForms application where I currently have a `DataGridView` as a Custom `UserControl` and seems to be having an issue with the `DataGridView` width not resizing as to where it is docked.

I have anchored the Custom datagridview `UserControl` with `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left` and `Right` as follows:

```
UserControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top || AnchorStyles.Bottom || AnchorStyles.Left || AnchorStyles.Right
```

Also tried setting the dock property of `DataGridView` to `Fill` however to no luck it seems to Fill the space as shown in the image attached. The custom UserControl itself is sitting perfectly however the DataGridView leaves a blank space after the last column. The border is the customer usercontrol itself.

Also set the DataGridView column property to Fill but to no avail.

```
DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);
```

[image]

Anybody have suggestions?

Comment: Set autosize to true. Remove anchor, set Docking.Fill

Comment: @MrgGek sorry is this on the GridView itself or UserControl container?

Comment: if you want to fit to the user control size then set it to both

Comment: The Image you posted doesn't explain much. Nor does your description. If you `Dock.Fill` a control inside a container. it will occupy all the available space. Unless another control occupies a section of the same container. The z-order can  determine who wins. Your context is, IMO, not clear. Since you alos tagged `[panel]` then you probably have a panel that takes part of the clientarea of the UC. Also, if your DataGridView is the control, then you have a Custom Control, not a UserControl. Thus, you don't really have a container. Give more details.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for the suggestion. Corrections made accordingly.

Comment: So, you have **Custom Control** (a control derived from DataGridView). That's importan: a UserControl (different stuff) has a designer and it's just a container. Now, you want to dock your Custom Control. Where? Directly inside a Form? Inside another container which is placed on the Form. Did you set the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` as shown in the answer here? Also, try setting the columns' FillWeight to `1`: it helps in speeding up the process. If your scenario is different, please clarify. The image you posted doesn't help much in qualifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

after binding to datasource, try below code:

```
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```